# How to click a particular Row in WpfCalendar of Flights Reservation Application in UFT

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

As per need, I want to select the Second Row from FlightsGrid Image shown below.
Applying below Code, I am getting RowCount as 6 but not able to click on 3rd Row.

```
Set ODesc = Description.Create
oDesc("micclass").value = "WpfTable"
Set objchild = WpfWindow("HPMyFlightSampleApplication").WpfTable("Table_FlightsGrid")
objCount = objchild.rowcount
objCount(2).click
```

Image from Flight Reservation Application:

[image]

Comment: Click that row using Flight number...?

Comment: @ManishChristian can you share the method for click operation. Object spy is not spying each row, rather it is taking entire WpfTable.

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WpfTable` object is not a collection, it doesn't support indexing. Did you try using its [`SelectRow`](http://uft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/14.00/UFT_Help/Subsystems/FunctionReference/Subsystems/OMRHelp/OMRHelp.htm#NET_WPF/WpfPackageLib~WpfTable.html#SelectRow) method?

Comment: I tried using SelectRow Method and it got selected. Working Fine for me as of now.

Answer (score 0):

First, why are  you using DP here if you are able to get row count of table.
Following two lines will give you row count of the table:

```
Set objchild = WpfWindow("HPMyFlightSampleApplication").WpfTable("Table_FlightsGrid")
objCount = objchild.rowcount
```

Second, try using its SelectRow method to select required row.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer, and format your reply.

Answer (score 0):

As @Motti suggested, you can use [**`SelectRow`**](http://uft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/14.00/UFT_Help/Subsystems/FunctionReference/Subsystems/OMRHelp/OMRHelp.htm#NET_WPF/WpfPackageLib~WpfTable.html#SelectRow). Or if you want to go more in depth and want to select particular cell (which will eventually select the entire row), you can use [**`SelectCell`**](http://uft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/14.00/UFT_Help/Subsystems/FunctionReference/Subsystems/OMRHelp/OMRHelp.htm#NET_WPF/WpfPackageLib~WpfTable.html#SelectCell) like this way:

```
'Rows and Columns indexes are 0-based
iCols = WpfWindow("devname:=HPE MyFlight Sample Application").WpfTable("devname:=flightsDataGrid").ColumnCount
iRows = WpfWindow("devname:=HPE MyFlight Sample Application").WpfTable("devname:=flightsDataGrid").RowCount

sFlightNum = "12274 NW"

For i = 0 To iRows
    If WpfWindow("devname:=HPE MyFlight Sample Application").WpfTable("devname:=flightsDataGrid").GetCellData(i, 4) = sFlightNum Then
        WpfWindow("devname:=HPE MyFlight Sample Application").WpfTable("devname:=flightsDataGrid").SelectCell i, 4
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Here is the screenshot:  [image]